# Does validation_split in tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory result in Data Leakage?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, tensorflow, cnn

For a binary image classification problem (CNN using tf.keras). My image data is separated into folders (train, validation, test) each with subfolders for two balanced classes. Borrowing code from [this tutorial](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/), I initially loaded my training and validation sets this way:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_path,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=42,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_path,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    seed=42,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)
```

Note that I am loading both training and validation from the same folder and then using validation_split (because I wanted to play around before using the real validation set). My model was performing quite well, achieving validation accuracy of~0.95.

Then I decided to update my code to load the real validation set:

```
train_ds = image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_path,
    seed=42,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)

val_ds = image_dataset_from_directory(
    val_path,
    seed=42,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)
```

Now my model is performing substantially worse (~0.75 accuracy). I'm trying to understand why. I suspect my initial code was causing some data leakage. Now that I look at it, I can't tell how the second call of image_dataset_from_directory (for val_ds) knows not to load images that were already loaded for the first call (for train_ds) (unless having the same random seed prevents this). I would be certain this is the issue, except for the fact that I pulled this code directly from a keras.io tutorial - surely they wouldn't make such a basic mistake?

**Main question:** Given the way that `validation_split` and `subset` interact with `image_dataset_from_directory()`, is the first version of my code resulting in data leakage?

If it should **not** be resulting in data leakage between training and validation sets, then I will need to consider other possibilities, such as:

- There are actual differences between images in the train and validation set folders. I could combine and reshuffle them.
- The order of images in the training folder is such that given my random seed "easier" images were getting pulled for the validation set.

Comment: validation split in Keras always uses the last $x$ percent of data as validation set. Could this be part of the problem?

Comment: @Peter - I had thought the shuffle=True default meant that the images are shuffled before the validation_split, but if the shuffle happens afterwords then this would definitely explain the issue (filenames of images are their lat/long coordinates so the last x images would all be from the same area). Do you know what order these operations happen in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible issue is that Keras `validation_split` uses the "last $x$ percent" of data as validation data *without shuffling* the data. So if your data has a certain stratification, this stratification will affect the validation set.

I further understand from the [docs](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/fit.html) that the `shuffle` argument in `.fit()` does not shuffle data before assigning the validation data. It shuffles training data before each epoch.

As far as I remember I had a similar problem and needed to "manually" shuffle my data before feeding it to the NN in order to avoid problematic bunching of classes in the validation set (defined by `validation_split`).

From the docs:

> **validation_split**
> Float between 0 and 1. Fraction of the training data
> to be used as validation data. The model will set apart this fraction
> of the training data, will not train on it, and will evaluate the loss
> and any model metrics on this data at the end of each epoch. The
> validation data is selected from the **last samples** in the x and y data
> provided, before shuffling.
>
> **shuffle**
> Logical (whether to **shuffle the training data before
> each epoch**) or string (for "batch"). "batch" is a special option for
> dealing with the limitations of HDF5 data; it shuffles in batch-sized
> chunks. Has no effect when steps_per_epoch is not NULL.

Comment: Yes - this is the issue. The filenames of my training data begin with latitude/longitude coordinates so validation_split was selecting a subset of images that are bunched together (ie not random). Thanks for the explanation!